# ACF no print data

Tags: categories, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I've a problem with [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

I create a custom field named: `bgcolor`

I want to print the value in  `category.php`, this is my code:

```
$color = get_field('bgcolor', 'category_'.the_category_ID( $echo ).'');
echo $color;
```

What its wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the field for the current category archive, not the category of the post inside the loop? Try `get_queried_object_id()` instead of `the_category_ID( $echo )`.

In `single.php`, you just need a slightly different iteration of your original attempt:

```
if ( $terms = get_the_category() )
    the_field( 'bgcolor', 'category_' . $terms[0]->term_id );
```

Comment: Its posible print the value in `category.php` and `single.php`?

Comment: See my revision.

Comment: Can you help me again?
How print data, for example: in loop `index.php`?

Comment: Just use my snippet inside your `while ( have_posts() )` loop - it will work for each post.

Comment: Can you help me with a ternary operator? I want to show a list of my categories in index page, i must use a ternary operators to display the field: http://pastebin.com/K8wxka0W
This code, return a blank div :/

Comment: @Ferrrmolina Post this as a new question titled "Only list category if it has a custom field image" & I'll answer there.